How to isolate a chip from a board without unsoldering it?
I have a board from some device with SPI flash memory chip. I also have a separate CH341a programmer for such chips and I intend to read the SPI flash memory chip from the board.
Now I want to do this without unsoldering the flash memory out of the board, because I'm lazy and not sure I can do it without damaging the board and chip contacts.
I've the SOP8/SOIC8 clips to connect the chip on-board, however there is another problem I don't know how to solve: when I connect the clips to the chip, it powering the whole board, not only the chip itself. This is a problem, because the processor on a board talks to the memory chip too, so I can't reliably do things with the memory chip with CH341a.
Ofc I can physically cut the tracks on the chip, but this is one-way process, I cant revert it back.
Is there any simple non-damage dealing way (maybe with some tool) to isolate the memory chip(not unsoldering it), so I can connect to it not powering on the whole board?
Or should I just give up with this and do unsoldering, as this is right way of doing so?

You can get sockets for SO-8 packages that have the exact same footprint as a normal SO-8 device.

There are a couple of things you can do here without physical modification...
System Reset
Are you able to hold the system in reset state?
If so, the I/O pins connected to the flash will generally become inputs / Hi-Z, and you are then able to drive them yourself without fighting. You can verify this using a resistor and multimeter in current mode - if you see more than ~10mA, then it's probably not safe to continue.
Additionally, be careful, as some designs have a reset signal that initiates a reset but does not hold the reset... in this case, the system will reset but then continue to operate, and the pins will not be Hi-Z.
Be careful, as if the #CS signal for this (or another part) is low during reset, then one or more devices may be driving part of the bus... again, verify that the signals are not being driven using a resistor and multimeter.
Reduced Supply Voltage
Some systems will have a Brown Out Detector (BOD), or other supervisory circuit implemented that will prevent things from running. If this is implemented, then certain items will typically be held in reset until a threshold is reached.
For example, if the system supply is nominally +3.3v (measure it), but the memory operates down to +1.8v, you could try injecting +1.8v on the VCC pin instead of the full +3.3v.
You'll need to verify the results (same as the "System Reset" approach), as many parts will operate over a fairly wide voltage range. If the BOD is internal, then you may also find it doesn't start operating until it's configured by the firmware, so a small delay may be required after applying power.
Discrete BOD or supervisory circuits are more commonly found on equipment that needs to be more robust, like industrial control systems, but internal BOD is often configured.
No Power?
You can also try accessing the SPI flash without power connected(?!) ... i.e: just CLK, COPI, CIPO, #CS and GND - no VCC.
In my experience, many such memories can be successfuly powered and read via the I/O protection alone (e.g: ESD protection diodes), and do not "strictly" require their power supply. Writing is often more demanding on the power, so this may not work or may be unreliable.
Be careful, as you may find you "backpower" the system using this approach, and this may allow it to startup "normally".
Of course I'd never suggest implementing this in a robust system, but if you read out the full memory a few times (full power cycle in between) and compare the result, it's possible you will be able to successfully extract the contents!
Physical Modification
If the above steps fail, then the final option is to look into physical modification. In many situations the power trace is visible and may be cut - you often won't need to cut the others, but you will need to verify the effects similarly to the "No Power?" approach..
If the power trace isn't visible, then based on the package you mentioned, you can attempt to lift just the power supply leg (obviously not possible for other package types).
Finally, you'll be forced into use hot air and/or desoldering braid to remove the whole IC.

Relying on power being fed through IO pins will not only power the memory chip but the whole board too, so at least that is not going to work. There will be protection diodes  from IO pin to supply pin. Same applies if you cut the supply pin but IOs connect to MCU, then board powers up from IO pins through MCU protection diodes. Only the suggestion to keep MCU in reset may work - but might not if there are other SPI devices on same bus and they are left possibly driving the bus with CS low.

@Justme thanks for your comment - I've added some wording to address what you mention. I've left the "wont work" items in, as I believe they have worked for me in the past - possibly as the voltage drop over these diodes was large enough that things didn't get enough power... I've also added a "reduced supply voltage" option.
